# Linked List Can't Connect Nodes

Tags: c, list

I created a list and i checked through the countnodes function if the nodes are connected. The countnodes functions gave me the right answer and i thought that everything it's okay. But , when i tried to delete a node i realised that the nodes are not even connected to the head. I know that the problem is in the insert function because  the cur always gives something different from zero and the insert function returns zero and the nodes never connect to each other.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node
{
    int datum;


    struct node *next;
};

struct node *search(struct node *head, int id, struct node **prev)
{
    struct node *tmp = 0;
    tmp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    *prev = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    tmp = head;
    printf("\n\ntmp->datum = %d",tmp->datum);

    while(tmp!=NULL && tmp->datum < id)
    {
        *prev = tmp;
        tmp = tmp->next;


    }

    if(tmp==NULL || tmp->datum != id)
    {

         return NULL;
    }


    return tmp;
};


int insert(struct node **H, struct node *tmp)
{
    struct node *cur = 0 , *prev = 0;
   // tmp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    cur = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    printf("\n\ninsert datum = %d\n\n",tmp->datum);
        cur = search(*H,tmp->datum,&prev);



    if(cur) return 0;
    printf("\nox\n");

    if(prev==NULL)
    {
        printf("\nNULL\n");
        tmp->next = *H;
        *H = &tmp;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nELSE\n");
        tmp->next = (prev->next);
        prev->next = tmp;
    }

    return 1;

}

int delete(struct node **h,int price)
{
    struct node *cur, *prev;
    cur = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    cur = search(*h,price,&prev);

    if(!cur) return 0;

    if(prev)
    {
        prev->next = cur->next;
        free(cur);
        printf("\n\nsimple delete\n\n");
    }
    else
    {
        *h = cur->next;
         free(cur);
         printf("\n\nhead delete\n\n");
    }

    return 1;
}

int countnodes(struct node *h)
{
    int n=0;
    struct node *tmp = 0;
    tmp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    tmp = h;
    while(tmp!=NULL)
    {
        n++;
        printf("\n\ndatum = %d\n",tmp->datum);
        tmp = tmp->next;



    }

    printf("\n\n\nNodes = %d\n",n);
    return n;

}

int main()
{
    struct node *head;
    struct node  *cur;
    int i=0;

    head = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    cur = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    head->datum = i;
    head->next = NULL;

    cur = head;

    for(i=1;i<5;i++)
    {

        cur->next = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

        insert(&head,cur);
        cur = cur->next;
        cur->datum = i;
        cur->next = 0;


    }



        delete(&head,0);
        //countnodes(head);



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Go easy on the `malloc`. There are eight instances of memory allocation in your program. There should only be one - namely when a new node is created. In every other case, your pointers should either point to existing nodes or be `NULL`. These pointers make up the links in your list.

Comment: I know you are right, but if i will remove the mallocs from the functions , the program is crushing

Comment: It's not just about removing your `mallocs`, you should also redesign your program so that all pointers are consistent. If your program crashes, that either means that a pointer is uninitialised or that you are following a `NULL` pointer. As I said: All pointers ahould point to valid nodes (which you get with `malloc`) or `NULL`. If a pointer `node` is `NULL`, you cannot dereference it with `*node` or `node->datum`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problems I see in your code:

1. In `search`:

   ```
   tmp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
   *prev = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
   ```

   These are unnecessary `malloc`s. They are also memory leaks. Change them to:

   ```
   *prev = NULL;
   ```
2. In `insert`:

   ```
   *H = &tmp;
   ```

   This line is wrong. The two sides are different pointer types. Perhaps this is a typo. It needs to be:

   ```
   *H = tmp;
   ```
3. In `delete`:

   ```
   cur = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
   ```

   This is also an unnecessary `malloc` and a memory leak.
4. In `countnodes`:

   ```
   tmp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
   ```

   This is also an unnecessary `malloc` and a memory leak.
5. In `main`:

   ```
   cur = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
   ```

   This is also an unnecessary `malloc` and a memory leak.

   Also, the following line doesn't server any purpose.

   ```
   cur = head;
   ```

   In the `for` loop, you have:

   ```
   cur->next = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
   insert(&head,cur);
   cur = cur->next;
   cur->datum = i;
   cur->next = 0;
   ```

   I think what you are trying to do is add a node whose `datum` is `i`. However, you are calling `insert` before setting the data on a node. What you need is:

   ```
   cur = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
   cur->datum = i;
   cur->next = 0;
   insert(&head,cur);
   ```

Hopefully I didn't miss anything.

**Update**

I missed another unnecessary `malloc` and memory leak. You don't need the following line in `insert`.

```
cur = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

Comment: I like how there is even a `malloc` in a function called `delete`.

Comment: @MOehm This points to an improper understanding of how to initialize pointers and when to allocate memory. Perhaps they heard from someone that a pointer is invalid until you allocate memory for it.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in several comments, the question code reveals an improper understanding of malloc() and pointers.

Below is a representation of the question code with a single `malloc()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node
   {
   int datum;
   struct node *next;
   };

struct node *search(struct node *cur, int id, struct node **prev)
   {
   while(cur && cur->datum < id)
      {
      *prev = cur;
      cur = cur->next;
      }

   if(cur)
      if(cur->datum != id)
         cur=NULL;

   return(cur);
   };

int delete(struct node **head, int price)
   {
   struct node *cur, *prev=NULL;

   cur = search(*head, price, &prev);
   if(NULL == cur)
      return 0;

   if(prev)
      {
      prev->next = cur->next;
      free(cur);
      }
   else
      {
      *head = cur->next;
      free(cur);
      }

   return 1;
   }

int countnodes(struct node *tmp)
   {
   int n=0;

   for(;tmp; tmp = tmp->next)
      n++;

   return(n);
   }

int insert(struct node **head, struct node *new)
   {
   struct node *cur = NULL;
   struct node *prev = NULL;

   if(*head)
      {
      cur = search(*head, new->datum, &prev);
      if(cur)
         return(0);
      }      

   if(prev)
      {
      new->next = prev->next;
      prev->next = new;
      }
   else
      {
      new->next = *head;
      *head = new;
      }

   return(1);
   }

int main()
   {
   struct node *head = NULL;
   int i;

   for(i=0;i<5;i++)
      {
      struct node *new = malloc(sizeof(*new));
      if(NULL == new)
         {
         fprintf(stderr, "malloc() failed\n");
         exit(1);
         }

      new->datum = i;
      new->next = NULL;
      printf("insert datum = %d\n", new->datum);
      insert(&head, new);
      }

   delete(&head,0);
   printf("countnodes = %d\n", countnodes(head));

   return 0;
   }
```